# How to get the values of this xml using linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following in my xml:

```
  <mur>
       <bak>
       </bak> 
        <itemfb ident="c_fb">
            <flow_m>
                <mat>
                <text texttype="text/plain">correct answer comments</text>
                </mat>
            </flow_m>
        </itemfb>
        <itemfb ident="gc_fb">
            <flow_m>
                <mat>
                <text texttype="text/plain">wrong, you made a blunder</text>
                </mat>
            </flow_m>
        </itemfb>
  </mur>
```

Now, the 'itemfb' tag, may or may not exist within a 'mur' tag and if exists, I need to parse and get the values "correct answer comments" (or) "wrong, you made a blunder" depending on "itemfb" ident. Here is what I have tried. Assume rowObj has the loaded xml from "mur" and 'ns' is the namespace

```
            if (rowObj.Elements(ns + "itemfb").Any())
            {
                var correctfb = (from cfb in rowObj
                                .Descendants(ns + "itemfb")
                                where (string)cfb.Attribute(ns + "ident").Value == "cfb"
                                select new
                                { 
                                ilcfb = (string)cfb.Element(ns + "mat")
                                }).Single();

            some_variable_1 = correctfb.ilcfb;



                var incorrectfb = (from icfb in rowObj
                                .Descendants(ns + "itemfb")
                                where (string)icfb.Attribute(ns + "ident").Value == "gcfb"
                                select new 
                                { 
                                ilicfb = (string)icfb.Element(ns + "mat")
                                }).Single();

            some_variable_2 = incorrectfb.ilicfb;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a way to get the information you want. I omitted ns for simplicity.

```
var correctfb = rowObj.Descendants("mur")
   .Descendants("itemfb")
   .Where(e => e.Attribute("ident").Value == "c_fb")
   .Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault();

if (correctfb != null)
    some_variable_1 = correctfb.Value;

var incorrectfb = rowObj.Descendants("mur")
   .Descendants("itemfb")
   .Where(e => e.Attribute("ident").Value == "gc_fb")
   .Descendants("text").FirstOrDefault();

if (incorrectfb != null)
    some_variable_2 = incorrectfb.Value;
```

Comment: This might work, but what happens if the tag doesn't exist. It throws an "object reference" exception at     ".Where(e => e.Attribute(ns + "ident").Value == "c_fb") "

Comment: ident may not exist inside itemfb?

Comment: If itemfb doesn't exist it also works, that is why I put FirstOrDefault() at the end. It could fail if ident doesn't exist within itemfb, but that was not in the constraints you mentioned. Anyway, there are ways to solve that.

Comment: No, ident exists in my context. If it doesn't, how would this change ?

Comment: You can replace that line with .Where(e => e.Attribute("ident") != null && e.Attribute("ident").Value == "c_fb"). But ident is an attribute that is part of itemfb, I guess it should exist always.

Comment: My bad, I was using ns + ident for the attribute text.